# Angularfire2 error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

My authentification service is throwing this error when I try to serve it

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'firebase'.

It also occurs when I try to build it in production mode throwing this error message:

> error TS2339: Property 'firebase' does not exist on type '{
>   production: boolean; }'.

I am using "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6" and "firebase": "4.10.1"

and this is my authentification service :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import * as firebase from '@firebase/app';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {MatSnackBar} from '@angular/material';

@Injectable()
export class AuthentificationService {
  user: Observable<firebase>;

  constructor(private firebaseAuth: AngularFireAuth, private router: Router,
    public snackBar: MatSnackBar) {
    // authentification initialisation
    this.user = firebaseAuth.authState;
  }

  // login
  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      .then(value => {
        console.log('Nice, it worked!');
        this.snackBar.open('Connection réussie', 'OK', {
          duration : 500
        });
        this.router.navigate(['/dataP']);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('Something went wrong:', err.message);
        this.snackBar.open('Echec de la connection', 'OK', {
          duration : 500
        });
      });
  }

  // logout
  logout() {
    this.firebaseAuth
      .auth
      .signOut();
  }

}
```

Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I think i found it :) ! I saw the tutorial that you followed, look at this line: 
import * as firebase from '@firebase/app';  remove the '@' before firebase !

Comment: I did as you say but the error remain in place

Comment: Restart serve , ng serve or ionic serve now

Comment: I shut the server down, clean the cacche then serve it , it is still showing me that error

Comment: Hold on now it is saying TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'firebase' as a type.

Comment: Why do you use it as type in observable ?

Comment: I was just following the guideline but I figure out the problem

Answer (score 1):

I figured out how to solve this probleme
I just change `user: Observable<firebase>;` to `user: Observable<firebase.User>;` and I have no error anymore